# whats are the differences between JAVA and .net in web based application development

Tags: java, .net, web

what are the differences between JAVA and .net and which one is better for developing web based application. Does JAVA has added advantage over .net?

Comment: this question is by far to generalizing to be answered.  There are books to fill with the features of java and .net based webapps

Comment: Java is language and .Net is framework... It is *really* confusing to find advantages of one over another.

Answer (score 2):

From the link:http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/39128

**.NET and Java are incomparable guided by the fact that .NET is a framework or simply a platform of presently 43 programming languages,where as Java is a programming language.**

> The ideal of Java has always been a Single language shared by multiple
>   Platforms. Whereas .Net is based on Multiple languages shared by
>   single Platform. Now come to derived differences from this major
>   difference.
>
> 1).Net has Multilanguage support. While java has based on java
>   language only. According to Microsoft latest news .Net support around
>   40 languages including major market share COBOL, Vb.net, C#.net, Perl
>   and many others.
>
> 2)Since java is multiplatform so it’s set of Framework Classes is
>   limited to what is available on all platforms. While .Net has set of
>   all the Classes available on Microsoft Platform.
>
> 3)According to Sun, Java is renowned as “Write once run anywhere”.
>   While .net has no such scene. But my perception is, its not completely
>   true to say “Write once run anywhere” but one aspect is that most of
>   the applications written today focus on one platform only. Similarly
>   to assure its multiple support much time needed to debug it on all
>   platforms. So I would like to say Sun that it’s not “Write once run
>   anywhere” but its “Write once and Debug everywhere.
>
> 4).Net due to disconnected data access through ADO.Net has hi level of
>   performance against Java JDBC which requires multiple round trips to
>   data base.
>
> 5)Java has support to open source platform while .Net has no direct
>   support for Open source Platforms.

Comment: If you really want comparison of this kind you may at least provide something more recent... there are some minor changes since 2006 :)

Comment: Java also is a platform hosting many programming languages (Scala, Groovy, Clojure and others); please don't confuse it with Java the language.

Net is just official implementation of CLR. Others exist too like Mono, which is cross-platform. .Net as of 2016 is cross platform in the form of .Net Core